# Remove Comma (,) from Date which is generated from Intl.DateTimeFormat

Tags: javascript, datetime-format

Using **Intl.DateTimeFormat** to get the time in a format similar to "15-Jan-2021, 2:30:11 pm".

```js
  function formatDate(date) {

const someDate = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-IN', {
  dateStyle: 'medium',
  timeStyle: 'medium',
 }).format(date);
 
 return someDate;
}

console.log(formatDate(1610701211000))
```

I am trying to remove the "," to get the date in a format similar to "15-Jan-2021 2:30:11 pm". As per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/formatToParts we would be able to use formatToParts(date) to get information separately and concat the necessary fields. However, trying to use formatToParts(date) in the below snippet throws "formatToParts is not a function" error.

How can I remove the "," that is being returned in the above snippet?

```js
function formatDate(date) {

    const someDate = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-IN', {
      dateStyle: 'medium',
      timeStyle: 'medium',
     }).format(date);
     
     // error thrown: formatToParts is not a function
     console.log(someDate.formatToParts(date));
     return someDate;
    }

    console.log(formatDate(1610701211000))
```

Comment: remove `.format(date)` to make `formatToParts` work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the formatToParts from the wrong object

You likely wanted  to just use a replace for the date

Here are both ways

```js
function formatDate(ms) {
  const date = new Date(ms)
  const formatter = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-IN', {
    dateStyle: 'medium',
    timeStyle: 'medium',
  })
  const someDate = formatter.format(date)

  const parts = formatter.formatToParts(date)

  // the hard way same as just doing a replace: 
  const fromParts = Object.values(parts)
    .map(({value}) => value === ", " ? " " : value)
    .join("")

  console.log(fromParts); 

  
  return someDate.replace(/, /g, " "); //  a simple replace removes the comma
}

console.log(formatDate(1610701211000))
```